# Filter query parameters

Tags: laravel-5.3

I'm trying to implement a filtering query parameter for my collection resource but I'm not sure on the best way to handle the query parameter. If I have a request like:

```
http://test.app/users?created_at>=2016-10-01
```

The resulting query parameter is:

```
{"created_at>":"2016-10-01"}
```

And if the request is:

```
http://test.app/users?created_at>2016-10-01
```

The resulting query parameter is:

```
{"created_at>2016-10-01":""}
```

Are there any existing solutions to handle these types of query parameters?

Comment: How about passing an array as query param? `http://test.app/users?created_at[min]=2016-10-01`

Comment: I'm liking that, now to see if the boss does...

Answer (score 1):

It's a bad practice to pass these type of operators via query string.

Use this format in your query string (citate from http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/comparison-ops.html):

- gt (greater than)
- ge (greater than or equal to)
- lt (less than)
- le (less than or equal to)

In your case, it should be like this: `http://test.app/users?created_at[ge]=2016-10-01` or this: `http://test.app/users?created_at=2016-10-01&comparison=ge`